# TypeError: Error #1006 in flash AS3 while trying to access main timeline from inside movie clip

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have placed a movie clip on the main timeline, with instance name `sq_mc`. Inside of it, there is `sq_motion_tween_mc`. `sq_motion_tween_mc` is empty, and I have converted it to movie clip, because it was required to apply motion tweening.

```
[1]------------------|[2]----------|
sq_mc                | ...
   |                 |
 sq_motion_tween_mc  |
```

There is a `stop();` action on both the 1st and 2nd keyframe of the main timeline.

I want to jump to the 2nd frame on the main timeline after playing last frame of `sq_mc`. 
Here's the code I have on the last frame of `sq_mc`:

```
sq_motion_tween_mc.sq_mc(parent).gotoAndPlay(2);
```

And I get this error message:

> TypeError: Error #1006: sq_mc is not a function.  at
>   Untitled_fla::square_1/frame24()

Note: `Square` is the name of the movie clip symbol for `sq_mc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The motion tween has no relevance whatsoever to what you are trying to do.  Also, if it's empty, I'm not sure what you are tweening...

Anyway, on the last frame of your Square MovieClip, do

```
MovieClip(parent).gotoAndStop(2);
```

That's it.

Comment: First of all I converted the graphics to movieclip while motion tweening 

because it asks to convert it to symbol. So I choosed movieclip as a symbol. 

Secondly, I'm getting this error after applying your code:                    

          Symbol 'sq_mc', Layer 'Layer 2', Frame 24, Line 1 1061: Call to 

a possibly undefined method gotoAndStop through a reference with static type 

flash.display:DisplayObjectContainer.

Comment: If you convert a drawing into a symbol, it is not empty - it contains the drawing! ;)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are trying to accomplish, you either do:

```
sq_mc.sq_motion_tween_mc.gotoAndPlay(2); // sq_motion_tween_mc's timeline.
```

or

```
sq_mc.gotoAndPlay(2); //sq_mc's timeline
```

or even

```
gotoAndPlay(2); //Main timeline
```

calling sq_mc(parent) is not legal if sq_mc is a MovieClip. The only function I see here is gotoAndPlay().

Comment: It gives error "1120 access of undefined property ..." while trying each of the 3 conditions you mentioned!!

Comment: Symbol 'Symbol 1', Layer 'Layer 2', Frame 1, Line 1 1120: Access of undefined property sq_mc. It applies for this sq_mc.gotoAndPlay(2); //sq_mc's timeline

Comment: So for sure sq_mc is a MovieClip with the instance name set as sq_mc? try this code and see what happens: `MovieClip(sq_mc).gotoAndPlay(2);` A common mistake I used to make is typing .goToAndPlay() instead of gotoAndPlay() (notice the "t" in "to" is lowercase.)

Comment: I tried setting sq_mc same for both movieclip name as well as instance name. Added  MovieClip(sq_mc).gotoAndPlay(2); on sq_mc timeline. Also verified any grammatical or syntax errors. But still getting same error 1120!!